# Encrypting Multiple Items with Cloud KMS

Tags: google-cloud-kms

How to invoke encryption API when we have multiple data to be encrypted at a single time? Suppose if we have 10 records and our requirement is to use encryption API only once. Then how it can be done?

Comment: I think there's no batch API for Cloud KMS, so you can either make one distinct request per data item (although grpc can parallelize these requests into a single network connection) or you can build an aggregate message with all your data items and pass it to KMS as a single request, which will have a single response that encrypts all the passed-in items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [KMS API request body reference](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.keyRings.cryptoKeys/encrypt#request-body):

```
{
  "plaintext": string,
  "additionalAuthenticatedData": string,
  "plaintextCrc32c": string,
  "additionalAuthenticatedDataCrc32c": string
}
```

This API takes only **one** plain text value. You can concatenate multiple data, but they will be all made into one encrypted text, and will have to be decrypted all at the same time.